# What is the meaning of sub-paragraph 3-9-6 j. in FAA JO 7110.65X?

Tags: faa-regulations

In [JO 7110.65X](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Order/JO_7110.65X_Air_Traffic_Control.pdf), section 3-9-6(j) says in reference to the 3 minute rule:

> j. Separate an aircraft behind another aircraft that has departed or
>   made a low/missed approach when utilizing opposite direction takeoffs
>   or landings on the same or parallel runways separated by less than
>   2,500 feet by the following minima:
>
> 1. Heavy, large, or small behind super − *4 minutes*.
> 2. Heavy, large, or small behind heavy − *3 minutes*

Do you think this applies to an aircraft in the pattern making approaches to the runway in use after a heavy departs opposite direction?

Comment: Welcome to Aviation.SE! Could you clarify your question as to what 'opposite direction' means, with respect to the approaching aircraft?

Answer (score 1):

If you search for the words "opposite direction" in the order it seems clear that they simply mean what they say, e.g. 3-9-7(a)(1):

> Separate a small aircraft weighing 12,500 lbs. or less taking off from
>   an intersection on the same runway (same or opposite direction
>   takeoff) [...]

This is confirmed in [JO7210.3AA](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/orders_notices/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1029468), *Facility Operation and Administration*:

> **2−1−31. OPPOSITE DIRECTION OPERATIONS**
>
> Opposite Direction Operations consists of IFR/VFR Operations conducted
>   to the same or parallel runway where an aircraft is operating in a
>   reciprocal direction of another aircraft arriving, departing, or
>   conducting an approach.